# Need to get the index of the largest value in teamScores[] and print the associated string with the matching index from teamNames[]

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

Need to get the index of the largest value in teamScores[] and print the associated string with the matching index from teamNames[]. This is really starting to get on my nerves. I had been able to successfully get the right value for the scores printed but it kept printing the wrong team. When I was trying to troubleshoot I was getting the right team but the wrong score. I am absolutely lost and have no other ideas. Anybody offer some advice? I have to use two separate arrays so I cannot just reduce it to one array. I also have to use a for loop to retrieve the values, so I can't do like I did with the lowScore.

```
public class SmithJustin_Asgn6 {

    public static int highScore(int[] teamScores, int highIndex) {
        
        int max = teamScores[0];
        for(int i = 0; i < teamScores.length; i++) {
                if(max < teamScores[i]) {
                    max = teamScores[i];
                    highIndex = i;
                    
                }
            }return highIndex;
    }
        
    
        
    public static int lowScore(int[] teamScores) {
        Arrays.sort(teamScores);
        int low = teamScores[0];
        return low;
        
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int highIndex = 0;
        
        Scanner userInput=new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner scoreInput=new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.print("Enter the number of teams would you like to enter data for: ");
        int teams=scoreInput.nextInt();
        
        int [] teamScores= new int[teams];
        String [] teamNames= new String[teams];
        
        for(int i = 0; i < teams; i++) {
            System.out.println("\nTeam "+ (i) +":");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.print("Enter Team's name: ");
            String teamName=userInput.nextLine();
            teamNames[i]=teamName;
            System.out.print("Enter Team's score (400-1000): ");
            int teamScore=scoreInput.nextInt();
            teamScores[i]=teamScore;
            System.out.println();
        }


        highScore(teamScores, highIndex);
        lowScore(teamScores);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("The high score is "+ teamScores[highScore(teamScores, highIndex)] +" by team " + teamNames[highScore(teamScores, highIndex)] + " and the low score is "+ lowScore(teamScores) +".");
        
        userInput.close();
        scoreInput.close();
    }

}
```

Been trying every way to slice it and I am completely stuck

Comment: You can create a class to store team name and its score. Then sort the array of class objects based on a comparator.

Comment: Your mistake is following: after lowScore gets called (you are calling there Arrays.sort), elements of array teamScores do not correspond anymore to the elements of array teamNames.

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov Holy crap!!! Thank you. Jesus Christ that was painful....I tweaked the code and rearranged. It is working perfectly, thanks for the nudge in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class to store team name and its score. Then sort the array of class objects based on a comparator. Also, you don't need to use two `Scanner` objects.

```
class Team
{
    public int score;
    public String name;
}

class SmithJustin_Asgn6 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.print("Enter the number of teams would you like to enter data for: ");
        int teams = userInput.nextInt();
        
        Team[] teamArray = new Team[teams];
        
        for(int i = 0; i < teams; i++) {
            teamArray[i] = new Team();
            userInput.nextLine();
            System.out.println("\nTeam "+ (i) +":");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.print("Enter Team's name: ");
            teamArray[i].name = userInput.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Enter Team's score (400-1000): ");
            teamArray[i].score = userInput.nextInt();
            System.out.println();
        }
        userInput.close();
        
        Arrays.sort(teamArray, new Comparator<Team>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Team o1, Team o2) {
                return Integer.compare(o1.score, o2.score);
            }
        });
        
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("The high score is "+ teamArray[teams - 1].score +" by team " + teamArray[teams - 1].name + " and the low score is "+ teamArray[0].score +".");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by [@Andrey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3426309/andrey-b-panfilov) your `Arrays.sort` is the main culprit. You need a logic to get the low score index the same as you have done for high score index.

```
public static int lowScore(int[] teamScores, int lowIndex) {
    // Arrays.sort(teamScores);
    int low = teamScores[0];
    //logic to low score's index
    return lowIndex;
}
```

After you have both the indexes, you can easily get values from respective arrays using them. 
In your `main` method you are calling the same methods multiple times instead of that  you can do

```
int lowIndex = 0;
highIndex = highScore(teamScores, highIndex);
lowIndex = lowScore(teamScores, lowIndex);
System.out.println();
System.out.println("The high score is " + teamScores[highIndex] + " by team " + teamNames[highIndex] + " and the low score is " + teamScores[lowIndex] + ".");
```

---

Start learning [`stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html). Its easy and fun ;).

```
int h1 = IntStream.range(0, teamScores.length)
                .reduce((i, j) -> teamScores[i] > teamScores[i] ? i : j)
                .getAsInt();
int lowScore = Arrays.stream(teamScores).min().getAsInt();
System.out.println("The high score is " + teamScores[h1] + " by team " + teamNames[h1]+ " and the low score is " + lowScore + ".");
```